# How to do multiclass classification with Hugging Face transformers using BERT

Tags: python, deep-learning, bert-language-model

I saw from an example that you can make a multiclass classifier with the Hugging Face transformers library by tweaking the label_list argument.

```
train_dataset = glue_convert_examples_to_features(examples=train_dataset, tokenizer=tokenizer
                                                  , max_length=5, task='cola'
                                                  , label_list =['0','1'])
valid_dataset = glue_convert_examples_to_features(examples=test_dataset, tokenizer=tokenizer
                                                  , max_length=5, task='cola'
                                                  , label_list =['0','1'])
```

The above seemed to work with an accuracy of around 70% after 2 epochs so I assumed that the code was working. Then I tried to use an Amazon product review dataset where "reviewText" fields were classified as a number between 1-5 in the "overall" field.The model still trained but accuracy was really low (.000ish) so I am not sure if the code is actually correct.

I know I left the 'cola' as a task argument which is a potential problem but is there anything else I am missing?

```
train_dataset = glue_convert_examples_to_features(examples=train_dataset, tokenizer=tokenizer
                                                  , max_length=5, task='cola'
                                                  , label_list =['1','2','3','4','5'])
valid_dataset = glue_convert_examples_to_features(examples=test_dataset, tokenizer=tokenizer
                                                  , max_length=5, task='cola'
                                                  , label_list =['1','2','3','4','5'])
```

Comment: Your `max_length` seems to be very low, but it can be your corpus specific!

Comment: oops, that was a typo, I used 128 in my a actual training. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: Its looking like that. Its hard to experiment through a full example because I only have a CPU

Comment: Yes, CPUs are bottleneck for such huge models.